# Find strictly subharmonic function vanishing at infinity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

I am not sure about the term "strictly" subharmonic.

What I want is a function $\psi\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ with $\Delta\psi>0$ and $\lim\limits_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}\psi(x)=0$.

I tried several times but still failed at the origin. I took $\psi=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{|x|}\right)-1$ with
$$\Delta\psi=\frac{1}{|x|^4}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{|x|}\right)>0$$

at every point $x\not=0$, and the boundary value does vanish, but $\Delta\psi(0)=0$.

Also, is this possible in $\mathbb{R}^2$? I want to use the comparison principle for the elliptic operator Laplacian $\Delta$ to disprove it, but that can only tell me $\psi<0$. How can I make use of the dimension? Or is this also possible?

Any help is desired.

Comment: I just cross-posted it on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384597/find-strictly-subharmonic-function-that-vanishes-at-infinity) as well.

Comment: It is already solved on MO via the link above. Beautiful ideas!